# value is not returning from another class

Tags: java, debugging

Hi I'm making a game where the player is met with a robot and the robot asks it to guess a number between 1-10. The player has three tries or they die. I've written all my code and the guessing works fine but whenever the play gets it right he still dies. I added a couple of print statements to see what value my code was returning and it seems to be returning the wrong value. Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Goes from this class

```
if (choice != -1) {
if (john[choice] != null) {
if (john[choice].compPlayerAttack()) {
 System.out.print("IT'S GAME OVER MAN!\n");
    System.exit(0);
}
else {
  System.out.println("Robot appears. Guess a number between 1-10. Get it right and you can pass, or you die. You have three chances.\"");
      int answer = 0;
      john[choice].toPass(answer);
      if (answer== 1) {
         System.out.println(answer);
          map[x][y].removeJohnPlayer();
         }
      else { System.out.println(answer);
        System.out.print("IT'S GAME OVER MAN!\n");
  System.exit(0);
  }
```

To this class

```
public int toPass(int right){


    int hiddenNum = numram.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numOfGuesses = 0;
    int a = right;

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a number by guessing: ");

        int guessedNum = input.nextInt();
        numOfGuesses++; 

        if (guessedNum == hiddenNum) {
            System.out.println("Darn! Your number is matched. You may live.");
            System.out.println("You have made " + numOfGuesses + " attempts to find the number!");

            a = 1;
             break;

        } else if (guessedNum < hiddenNum) {
            System.out.println("Try a bigger number");


        } else if (guessedNum > hiddenNum) {
            System.out.println("Try a smaller number");

        }    

}   while (numOfGuesses < 3);
System.out.println(a);
return a;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
john[choice].toPass(answer);
```

you are ignoring the value returned by your `toPass` method.

Change it to:

```
answer = john[choice].toPass(answer);
```

BTW, there's no reason to pass an argument to your `toPass` method, since it makes no use of it, and it can't change it (since Java is a pass by value language). A return value is enough.

i.e. change your method to `public int toPass()`.

Another change you should make is to change the return type to `boolean`. Returning `true` or `false` is more readable than returning `1` or `0`.